# Node/Express: Trying to send static JSON file to API endpoint

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am working on a MEAN stack app, and I'm trying to create a couple of API endpoints that the Angular client can `$http.get`, with simple JSON files populated with dummy data.

Here's the `orders.json` file I'm trying to test it with:

```
[
  {
    "order_status":"Shipped",
    "order_qty":30
  },
  {
    "order_status":"Shipped",
    "order_qty":6
  }
]
```

For example, the api route to $http.get:

```
apiRouter.get('/:fileName', queries.getStaticJSONFileForDevelopment);
```

But when I try to use express's `sendFile` method with a local .json file, like `orders.json`:

```
queries.js:

exports.getStaticJSONFile = function(req, res) {

  var fileName = req.params.fileName;
  console.log('path: ' + path.normalize(__dirname + '/' + fileName));

  res.sendFile(path.normalize(__dirname + '/' + fileName), function(err) {
    if (err) return res.send({ reason:error.toString() });
  });
};
```

The `console.log` tells me I'm pointed at the correct path to the file, but Postman delivers this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.exports.getStaticJSONFile [as handle] (path/to/queries.js:260:7)
// queries.js:260:7 points to the 's' in 'sendFile' above
```

However, when I just send the json data by itself:

```
res.send([{"order_status":"Shipped","order_qty":30},{"order_status":"Shipped","order_qty":6}]);
```

...the endpoint renders the data as you would expect. Am I trying to get the sendFile method to do something it's not meant to do, or is there something I'm missing? Thanks very much for any advice you may have!

Comment: You want to answer with file attached or You want to response with content-type: application/json  ?  maybe You want read json file and output json data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to read json file and response with json so You can try this:

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

exports.getStaticJSONFile = function(req, res) {

  var fileName = req.params.fileName;
  var file = path.normalize(__dirname + '/' + fileName);
  console.log('path: ' + file);

  jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    if(err) {
      res.json({status: 'error', reason: err.toString()});
      return;
    }

    res.json(obj);
  });
};
```

Comment: After reading your comment, i went back and tried this instead: ` fs.readFile(path.normalize(__dirname + '/' + fileName), 'utf8', function (err,data) { if (err) { return console.log(err); } res.send(data); });`, which worked like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: interesting thing: why You don't serve json file as static file? (:

Comment: do you mean why not serve it to the client as static file? just trying to mock data acquisition, because eventually the data at the API endpoint will be coming from external databases.

Comment: Yeah, understood. It's also helpful when You want restrict it to some group of users or use auth token and etc (:

Comment: indeed, it's `res.send(..)` and not `res.json(..)`

Comment: @SaadBenbouzid  res.json is excplicit version of res.send. it defines Content-Type: application/json even if data is not jsonable. reference: https://www.codingdefined.com/2016/06/difference-between-ressend-and-resjson.html?m=1